# Populating JSON objects in DataTables

Tags: ajax, json, datatables

I'm using DataTables 1.10.x and would like to populate the data in my table using JSON objects.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#diagtable').dataTable( {
        "ajax": '/api/v1/diag/1/',
        "columns": [
            { "date": "date" },
            { "diagnosis": "diagnosis" }
        ],
        dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    } );
} );
```

I realize the `{ "date": "date" },` does not look right, but I'm unsure what else to use in between the first quotes.

My table goes below:

```
<table id="diagtable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Diagnosis</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My AJAX call returns the following JSON:

```
[
    {
        "date":"2010-03-20",
        "diagnosis":"Test1"
    },
    {
        "date":"2015-03-21",
        "diagnosis":"Test2"
    }
]
```

I see the proper AJAX call is made by DataTables (HTTP 200), but the table says "loading...".

I tried playing around with the below, but still no data gets populated in my table.

```
"aoColumns": [
   { "mData": "date" },
   { "mData": "diagnosis" }
]
```

The [documentation](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/ajax/objects.html) shows to use:

```
    "columns": [
        { "data": "name" },
        ...
```

But I don't have this "data" or similar in my JSON. I cannot change my JSONs either.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your returned data in JSON format differs from the default format expected by DataTables 1.10.x, see [ajax.dataSrc](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc#Default) or [Ajax data source (objects)](http://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html) example.

Since you mentioned that you cannot change your JSON structure, the solution is to alter `dataSrc` property, see below

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#diagtable').dataTable( {
        "ajax": {
            "url": '/api/v1/diag/1/',
            // Get JSON data from a plain array 
            // rather than an array in an object
            "dataSrc": ""
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "date" },
            { "data": "diagnosis" }
        ],
        dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, at least now I get two lines in my table (previously just "loading..."), but they are empty. I get `DataTables warning: table id=antetable - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4`. I visited that page - not sure why the error is thrown. Both objects are in string representation. I also tried changing my column names to (lowercase) `date` and `diagnosis`, but no luck getting data into the table.

Comment: Sorry, I missed another problem in the initialization code with `columns.data` property and updated my answer.